# Call codeigniter controller from external script

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the best way to execute a codenighter controller/method from an external script?

Trying to integrate my existng CI app with a non-CI app and need to get output of CI and show it inside the other app.

Comment: maybe iframe will suit? or ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at either the xmlrpc library or rest (baseed on https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver).

Another option is you could set up a controller/view method that outputs the info you need in a format that you can work with and use curl to get that page.

Answer (score 0):

ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'controller/method',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This would work in theory but would result in bad SEO as the content would not be visible on page.

Comment: Ah, well thanks for specifying that requirement in the question.